# How do I keep an object always in front of everything else in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, viewport, clipping, foreground, depth

I have this function which draws a small 3D axis coordinate system on the bottom left corner of the screen but depending on what I have in front of me, it may get clipped.

For instance, I have drawn a plain terrain on the ground, on the XZ plane at Y = 0. The camera is positioned on Y = 1.75 (to simulate an average person's height). If I'm looking up, it works fine, if I'm looking down, it gets clipped by the ground plane.

Looking up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0i6g.png
Looking down: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5LIx.png

The function I call to draw the axis system on the corner is this:

```
void Axis3D::DrawCameraAxisSystem(float radius, float height, const Vector3D rotation) {
    if(vpHeight == 0) vpHeight = 1;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, vpWidth, vpHeight);
    gluPerspective(45.0f, 1.0 * vpWidth / vpHeight, 1.0f, 5.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);

    glRotatef(-rotation.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(-rotation.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    DrawAxisSystem(radius, height);
}
```

An now a couple of main functions I think are relevant to the problem:

```
glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);

void changeSize(int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) height = 1;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    gluPerspective(60.0f, 1.0 * width / height, 1.0f, 1000.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void renderScene(void) {
    glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    changeSize(glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));

    glLoadIdentity();

    SceneCamera.Move(CameraDirection, elapsedTime);
    SceneCamera.LookAt();

    SceneAxis.DrawCameraAxisSystem(0.03f, 0.8f, SceneCamera.GetRotationAngles());

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You were given apropriate answers already. But there's one thing you must understand: OpenGL doesn't treat geometry as "objects" (an OpenGL object is something different, a texture for example, or a vertex buffer). OpenGL is a rasterizer and a picture is built one triangle at a time. Because of that asking "how to keep an object in front", while perfectly understandable, doesn't address the actual issue. What you wanted to know is, how to reliably draw something on top of the preexisting content of the framebuffer, while still being able to use depth testing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Rather than disable depth testing, you can just `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` before you render your overlay.  Then whatever depth information was there is gone, but the pixels are all still there.  However, your overlay will still render appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

You could also reserve a tiny bit of the depth range for your 3D axis. And all the rest for your scene. Like this:

```
// reserve 1% of the front depth range for the 3D axis
glDepthRange(0, 0.01);

Draw3DAxis();

// reserve 99% of the back depth range for the 3D axis
glDepthRange(0.01, 1.0);

DrawScene();

// restore depth range
glDepthRange(0, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to disable depth testing (so it's not clipped by anything):

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

and if you've pre-transformed the points (it doesn't appear you have), set the view and projection matrices to identity.

**Edit:**

If you need the axis bit to stay tested and in order, then you'll probably want to clear the depth buffer (`glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`) between rendering it and your main scene. That will reset the depth buffer so that the marker is drawn (and so appears in front), but is still properly culled.

Comment: If I disable depth testing just before drawing the axis system, the axis itself will look weird with no depth between the 3 axis. Is it possible to disable depth testing between the 2 viewports only? I'm not sure what you mean with "pre-transformed the points" but the identity matrix is loaded after setting each matrix mode, am I missing anything?

Comment: If your geometry is right, then the matrices are. To fix the scene without breaking the axis, see the edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try enabling blending, then set alpha & color manually in a fragment shader.  But that might be overkill ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`glGetBooleanv(GL_BLEND,       &m_origin_blend);

glGetBooleanv(GL_DEPTH_TEST,&m_origin_depth);

glGetBooleanv(GL_CULL_FACE, &m_origin_cull);

setAlphaBlending(true);

setDepthTest(false);

setCullFace(false); //by stone

//your draw() ...

setAlphaBlending(m_origin_blend>0?true:false);

setDepthTest(m_origin_depth>0?true:false);

setCullFace(m_origin_cull>0?true:false);`